# I need a countdown timer that works simultaneously

Tags: javascript, countdown

1. Hi guys? please i need help, i want a situation whereby after a
   certain time, the first timer should stop counting, while the second
   timer executes and update "BREAK TIME" in a way that if the page is
   refresh, the first timer would not execute until the second timer finish executing and vice versa.

   ```
   <script>


    let element = document.querySelector('#countdown');
       let breakTime = document.querySelector("#countdownbreak"),myD=true;
       function TimeFii(){
         time_difference = (60*1) -(((Date.now()-localStorage.getItem('realTime'))/1000) | 0); //60 if duration = 60*1
         hours = (time_difference/3600) | 0;
         minutes = ((time_difference % 36000) / 60)  | 0;
         seconds = (time_difference %60)|0;
         hours = hours<10 ? "0"+hours:hours
         minutes =  minutes < 10 ? "0"+minutes:minutes//00
         seconds = seconds <10 ?"0"+seconds:seconds
           uniseconds = seconds;
           element.textContent = minutes+":"+seconds;
           if(time_difference<=0){
             var start = Date.now()+100;`enter code here`
             localStorage.setItem('realTime',start);
           }
           if(seconds==39){
             stop();
             resetFii();
             element.innerHTML =""
             localStorage.setItem('noStart',myD)
             startFiiTimer(TimeFiiBreak);
           }
       }

       function TimeFiiBreak(){
         time_difference = (60*3) -(((Date.now()-localStorage.getItem('realBTime'))/1000) | 0); //60 if duration = 60*1
         hours = (time_difference/3600) | 0;
         minutes = ((time_difference % 36000) / 60)  | 0;
         seconds = (time_difference %60)|0;
         hours = hours<10 ? "0"+hours:hours
         minutes =  minutes < 10 ? "0"+minutes:minutes//00
         seconds = seconds <10 ?"0"+seconds:seconds
           uniseconds = seconds;
           breakTime.textContent = "BREAK TIME:"+minutes+":"+seconds;
           if(time_difference<=0){
             var start = Date.now()+100;
             localStorage.setItem('realBTime',start);
           }
           if(seconds==40){
             stopB();
             resetBFii();
             startFiiTimer(TimeFii);

           }
       }

       function startFiiTimer(fun){
         return setInterval(fun,100);
       }


       function resetFii(){
           return localStorage.removeItem('realTime');
       }
       function stop(){
         return clearInterval(TimeFii)
       }

       function resetBFii(){
           return localStorage.removeItem('realBTime');
       }
       function stopB(){
         return clearInterval(TimeFii)
       }
       window.onload = function (){
         if(myD !=false){
           startFiiTimer(TimeFii);
         }
       }

   </script>
   ```

   Please the snippet above runs, but not as exactly as i want, you can visit fastplay24.com to see an example of the timer. thanks

Comment: `you can visit <some nigerian website so that's probably safe> to see an example of the timer` - except there's no obvious timer there, prince

Comment: on fastplay24.com, check out everything there, the timer was written on angular, but i want to make mine in pure javascript

Answer (score 0):

setInterval() returns a timer id, you need to use that when you call clearInterval(), not the function itself. Something like:

```
idtimerfii = setInterval(fun,100);

clearInterval(idtimerfii)
```